# Require only 2 of 3 form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a yield calculator. There are 3 fields. Yield Percentage, Purchase Price, and Rent.

For example, I want a 10% yield, and I pay 500k, then my calculator will get the monthly rent to achieve the 10% yield.
Also, If I want a 10% yield, and I input a monthly rent of 500, then my calculator gets the purchase price.
Lastly, If I pay 500k, and let the rent be 500, then my calculator would get the yield percentage.

```
<form>
   <input type="number" name="purchase_price">
   <input type="number" name="rent">
   <input type="number" name="yield">
   <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

FURTHERMORE:

how do I make it that if any 2 of the fields are populated, the 3rd one get's disabled?

Example:

price & rent = yield field gets disabled

price & yield = rent field gets disabled

rent & yield = price field gets disabled

Comment: Please show some code. What does you HTML look like?

Comment: @ObjectManipulator there.

Comment: @ObjectManipulator i updated my question, can you help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my code sample I am targeting all inputs that is not the submit button. So if you have an input field somewhere else this will deactivate it. I am using it for simplicity and you should add an id or class to your form.

```js
    var form = document.querySelector('form'); 

    form.addEventListener('change',function(event){
     elms = document.querySelectorAll('input:not([type="submit"]');
      var count = 0; 
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(elms,function(elm){
             if (elm.value != ''){
                 count++; 
              }
        });
       
       Array.prototype.forEach.call(elms,function(elm){
             if (count >= 2 && elm.value === ''){
                 elm.disabled = true; 
               }
             else{
               elm.disabled = false;
               }
        });
      
    });
```

```html
  <form>
       <input type="number" name="purchase_price">
       <input type="number" name="rent">
       <input type="number" name="yield">
       <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
    </form>
```

Comment: when i erase my input, it doesn't enable the disabled field

Comment: I think your querySelectorAll might need thinking as there might be other inputs in the page. :/

Comment: @ShrikanthBuds I understand. There is no element in his markup so keeping it simple.

Comment: @yasinYaqoobi in that case I suggest you to use input[type='number] instead of input type of not-submit :)

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi or I can use a class right? i think this is correct already :D

Comment: @PaulLucero yes, that's the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form id="calculator">
  Price <input type="number" name="purchase_price" class="input"><br/>
  Rent <input type="number" name="rent" class="input"><br/>
  Yield <input type="number" name="yield" class="input"><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

Now, your jQuery code:

```
$("#calculator").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var blank = 0;
    $('.input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
           blank++;
        }
    });
    if (blank <= 1) {
        //console.log("Submitted!");
        $(this).submit();
    }
 });
```

Refer to JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ahpj6o6h/4/

Comment: i see. i'll try this. let you know afterwards :D